# Execute swift code in order

Tags: ios, swift

I need the "getUserInfo" to complete before I execute the next section of code (the push to storyboard). Currently the "getUserInfo" is still in process while the storyboard push executes. How can I make these execute in order? I'm need to keep these 2 functions separate, so putting the code in the completion handler of loginUser isn't a good solution. Many thanks to those who are smarter than me :)

```
func loginUser() {
        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(txtEmailAddress.text, password:txtPassword.text) {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if user != nil {

                // Successful login.
                self.txtPassword.resignFirstResponder()
                self.txtEmailAddress.resignFirstResponder()

                getUserInfo()

                // Push to Main.storyboard.
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
                let viewController: AnyObject = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
                self.presentViewController(viewController as! UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else {
                // The login failed. Display alert.
                self.displayAlert("Error", message: "Login incorrect")
            }
        }
}

func getUserInfo() {

    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    let userQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")

    userQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)

    userQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (results:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for result in results! {
                userType = result["userType"] as! String

                if userType == "admin" {
                    user = "AdminSetting"
                } else {
                    user = "StandardSetting"
                }
            }
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: Don't execute in background.

Comment: "so putting the code in the completion handler of loginUser isn't a good solution." What does this have to do with keeping them in separate functions. Keep them in separate functions, and call the other function in the completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is make the asynchronous function (the one with the completion handler) synchronous, so that it returns immediately. However that's usually a bad idea, because if the execution stops in the main thread, the user can't do anything and your app is stuck until the code continues again. This might take a couple seconds depending on the connection, which isn't very good, you should really update your UI asynchronous on asynchronous tasks. There usually aren't good reasons to do something like this, if you have them though, you can tell me.

Comment: I can't figure out a better way to do this. Once the user logs in, I need to know the type of user they are. Based on this, I decide which options to show them. I don't know the user until they log in, so I can't do it earlier. I'm new to this, so very open to suggestions. Certainly appreciate your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

You could also execute your storyboard code within getUserInfo() as a block/closure passed in as a parameter.  That way you can ensure it is executed when the async call in getUserInfo completes

Answer (score 0):

What Shadowman suggested is the correct/most elegant solution.

Here is an example:

```
func getUserInfo(completion: (results:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void) {

    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    let userQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")

    userQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)

    userQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(completion)

}
```

This way, you get back the actual results from your call after it finished, handy, eh ?

And here is how you call it:

```
self.getUserInfo { (results, error) -> Void in

    // Here the results are already fetched, so proceed with your 
    // logic (show next controller or whatever...) 

    if error == nil {
        for result in results! {
            userType = result["userType"] as! String

            if userType == "admin" {
                user = "AdminSetting"
            } else {
                user = "StandardSetting"
            }
        }
    }

    // depending on whether this will still run in a background thread, you might have to dispatch this code to the main thread.
    // you can check whether this code block is called on the main thread
    // by checking if NSThread.isMainThread() returns true
    // if not, you will need to use this dispatch block!
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        // only call UI code in main thread! 
        // MOVE TO NEXT controller in here!
    })
}
```